# Java How to prevent fill item in JScrollPane

Tags: user-interface, size, jscrollpane, fill

I'm trying to make Item In JScrollPane dynamically.

but when i add JPanel(for represent item) that Panel fill all Scroll area.

when I add 2 JPanel item, it divide and also fill all Scroll Area.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMzCs.png)

'Green' Area mean Item Area this pic is when I add one Item to Scroll Area.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czl2P.png)

'cyan' color mean another item. this pic is when i add second Item to Scroll Area

I want fix each item's height (And fill width)

when I add item that item adding to Scroll Pane Area, and left area remain empty space.

how can i do this?

below is my code.

Thanks.

```
public class JPanelINScrollPanel extends JFrame{

public JPanelINScrollPanel(){

    this.setSize(700,700);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JPanel basePanel = new JPanel();

    JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane();

    JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();

    JPanel itemPanel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel itemPanel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel itemPanel3 = new JPanel();

    basePanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    getContentPane().add(basePanel);
    basePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));


    scrollPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    basePanel.add(scrollPanel);

    listPanel.setSize(500,500);
    listPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    listPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(listPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


    scrollPanel.add(listPanel);
    scrollPanel.setViewportView(listPanel);

    //itemPanel1.setSize(50,50);
    itemPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    itemPanel1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    listPanel.add(itemPanel1);




}

public static void main(String[] args){

    JPanelINScrollPanel test = new JPanelINScrollPanel();

    test.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple

just setMaximumSize to item panel.

it's solved.

Comment: Thanks. it's helpful.